# How to link workitem or wiki page to an existed code in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

My company starts using Azure DevOps and we pushed our existing project to its github repository.
We are writing the manual and the old change's log at the DevOps' Wiki, and we want to link the wiki with the existing code. I've read that it is posible to link code to work items when you do a commit, but, since the project already exists, this isn't posible. Is there any way to link the a DevOps' wiki page to a code that already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1, To link work items to existed code.

You can add commits to a workitem by click the **Add link**  in **Development** section on the workitem edit page. Check out below screenshot.

[image]

2, To link wiki page to existed code.

You can add a link in the wiki page to the commit or code url.

First select the commit in **Commits** page under **Repos**. And copy the url of the commit from the address bar of your browser. Then you can add the link in the wiki page.

You can link the **Link icon** to add the link from the wiki edit page, or you can type `[text](url)` directly, as wiki suppports markdown language. Markdown syntax is supported in many other places in azure devops. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops) for more information.

[image]

Hope above helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can link commit to work item also after you do the commit:

[image]

[image]